# div open and close speed when mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to delay opening and closing a div smoothly when mouse hover.this is my code,

```js
function show_panel1()
{
document.getElementById('hoverpanel1').style.display="block";
}

function hide_panel1()
{
document.getElementById('hoverpanel1').style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 slideanim" onMouseOver="show_panel1()" onMouseOut="hide_panel1()">
      <div class="thumbnail panel">
        <img src="images/hospital.jpg" alt="Paris">
        <h3><strong>Service1</strong></h3>
        <div class="" id="hoverpanel1" style="display:none;">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porta dictum turpis, eu mollis justo gravida ac. Proin non eros blandit, rutrum est a, cursus quam. Nam ultricies, velit ac suscipit vehicula, turpis eros sollicitudin lacus, at convallis mauris magna non justo. Etiam et suscipit elit. Morbi eu ornare nulla, sit amet ornare est. Sed vehicula ipsum a mattis dapibus. Etiam volutpat vel enim at auctor.</p>
          <h3 style="font-size:20px;">NEW PETS FOR SALE!</h3>
          <?php include"panelcarousel.php"; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I found this source but I have no idea how to use it.
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: jQuery can provide your the tools you need to do that :) ! example : https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Describe what you mean by "display smoothly." Slide in? Change size? Fade? You are using CSS `display` to hide/show, so that will not animate. Choose an animation effect you want to see, describe it, and my guess is you can do it with native CSS animations and do not need script (let alone jQuery).

Comment: Charan Kumar gave me what i want mate.thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Use below snippet if it satisfies your requirement.

```js
function show_panel1()
{
$('#hoverpanel1').slideDown();
}

function hide_panel1()
{
$('#hoverpanel1').slideUp();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 slideanim" onMouseEnter="show_panel1()" onMouseLeave="hide_panel1()">
      <div class="thumbnail panel">
        <img src="images/hospital.jpg" alt="Paris">
        <h3><strong>Service1</strong></h3>
        <div class="" id="hoverpanel1" style="display:none;">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porta dictum turpis, eu mollis justo gravida ac. Proin non eros blandit, rutrum est a, cursus quam. Nam ultricies, velit ac suscipit vehicula, turpis eros sollicitudin lacus, at convallis mauris magna non justo. Etiam et suscipit elit. Morbi eu ornare nulla, sit amet ornare est. Sed vehicula ipsum a mattis dapibus. Etiam volutpat vel enim at auctor.</p>
          <h3 style="font-size:20px;">NEW PETS FOR SALE!</h3>
          <?php include"panelcarousel.php"; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```